# VSCode Search Selected Text in File Search Input

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I constantly use the file search input in the image below.

[image: Screenshot]

While any text is selected, is there a shortcut that will type that text into this input and search for it?

### UPDATE:

Finally I found a solution about this. You can add new shortcut like this:

```json
{
    "key": "shift shift",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
        "commands": [
            "editor.action.clipboardCopyAction",
            "workbench.action.quickOpen",
            "editor.action.clipboardPasteAction"
        ]
    },
    "when": "editorHasSelection"
}
```

Comment: `Ctrl + C`, `Ctrl + P`, `Ctrl + V`?

Comment: Yes but I just want a single shortcut for this :)

Comment: you can use `runCommands` to chain the commands attached to these key bindings to a single keybind of your choice